User definable function not working with Visual Studio but does with GCC
Trying to get a user definable function instead of what is in an API library. This works no problem in Linux GCC but cannot figure out what to do for Visual Studio. The library is a .dll and everything is the same on the .so in linux.
Header:
typedef struct _usb_can_packet_ {
    uint8_t             size;
    uint8_t             cmd;
    uint8_t             port;
    uint8_t             misc;
    uint32_t            extendedStatus;
    union {
        MCAN_OPEN           openInfo;
        MCAN_RX_PACKET      rxPacket;
        MCAN_TX_PACKET      txPacket;
        MCAN_TX_DONE        txEvent;
    } u;
} VL_USB_CAN_XFER;

void user_CANRxCallBackFunction(VL_USB_CAN_XFER* pRxPacket, int txStatus);

DLL:
// User Defined function called when a packet is recieved.
void user_CANRxCallBackFunction(VL_USB_CAN_XFER* pRxPacket, int status)
{
    /* ***** Declarations. ***** */
    /* ************************* */

    /* ***** Initializations. ***** */
    /* **************************** */

    /* ***** Construct the packet. ***** */
    if (gCallBackInfo.rxFlag)
    {
        if (gAPIDebugLevel >= VL_DEBUG_1)
        {
            printf("Entering user_CANRxCallBackFunction() with an event\n");
        }

        gCallBackInfo.rxFlag = 1;  // Reset the flag for next packet.

        if (gAPIDebugLevel >= VL_DEBUG_1)
            printf("Leaving user_CANRxCallBackFunction()\n");
    }

    /* ********************************* */
}


void rxCallBack(struct libusb_transfer* pXfer)
{
    /* ***** Declarations. ***** */
    VL_USB_CAN_XFER* pRxPacket;
    /* ************************* */

    // We are here.
    if (gAPIDebugLevel >= VL_DEBUG_2)
        printf("Entering rxCallBack()\n");

    gRxPacketCount++;
    if (LIBUSB_TRANSFER_COMPLETED == pXfer->status)
    {
        if (gAPIDebugLevel >= VL_DEBUG_2)
        {
            printf("Status complete;\n");

            printf("  usb->flags=0x%x\n", pXfer->flags);
            printf("  usb->actual_length=0x%x\n", pXfer->actual_length);
        }

        gCallBackInfo.rxFlag = 1;
        gCallBackInfo.rxSts = (int)pXfer->flags;
        gCallBackInfo.rxLength = (int)pXfer->actual_length;
        memcpy(gCallBackInfo.pRxBuf, pXfer->buffer, pXfer->actual_length);
        gRxTimeOutCount = 0;

        // For ease of reference, create a CAN packet.
        pRxPacket = (VL_USB_CAN_XFER*)gCallBackInfo.pRxBuf;

        // Filter out certain packets.
        switch (pRxPacket->cmd)
        {
        case USB_CAN_CMD_OPEN:
        case USB_CAN_CMD_CLOSE:
        case USB_CAN_CMD_ID:
        case USB_CAN_CMD_MAX:
        case USB_CAN_CMD_UNDEFINED:
            break;  // Do nothing for these.
        case USB_CAN_CMD_TX:
            if (gAPIDebugLevel >= VL_DEBUG_2)
            {
                VSL_CANPrintPktHeader("rxCallBack():", pRxPacket);
            }
            break;
        case USB_CAN_CMD_STS:
            gCANPortStatus = pRxPacket->misc;
            break;
        case USB_CAN_CMD_MCU_FW_VER:
            gMCUFwReceived = pRxPacket->extendedStatus;
            break;
        case USB_CAN_CMD_MCU_REG_VAL:
            gMCURegValReceived = pRxPacket->extendedStatus;
            gMCURegId = pRxPacket->misc;
            if (gAPIDebugLevel >= VL_DEBUG_2)
            {
                printf("\trxCallBack(): reg 0x%d val = 0x%08x\n",
                    gMCURegId, gMCURegValReceived);
            }
            break;
        case USB_CAN_CMD_RX:
            if (gAPIDebugLevel >= VL_DEBUG_2)
            {
                VSL_CANPrintPktHeader("rxCallBack(): RX", pRxPacket);
                mydumpData((uint8_t*)&(pRxPacket->u.rxPacket.mcanRxData), 8);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    else if (LIBUSB_TRANSFER_TIMED_OUT == pXfer->status) {
        if (gAPIDebugLevel >= VL_DEBUG_1)
        {
            if (gAPIDebugLevel >= VL_DEBUG_2)
                printf("Status timed_out;\n");
        }
        gRxTimeOutExit = true;
        gRxTimeOutCount++;
    }
    else if (LIBUSB_TRANSFER_CANCELLED == pXfer->status) {
        if (gAPIDebugLevel >= VL_DEBUG_2)
            printf("Status cancelled;\n");
        gRxCancelled = true;
        gRxTimeOutCount = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (gAPIDebugLevel >= VL_DEBUG_2)
            printf("UNKNOWN STATUS (%d);\n", pXfer->status);
    }

    // Call a user defined function.
    (void)user_CANRxCallBackFunction(pRxPacket, pXfer->status);

    libusb_submit_transfer(pXfer);

    if (gAPIDebugLevel >= VL_DEBUG_2)
        printf("Leaving rxCallBack(rxPacketCount=%d; rxTimeOutCount=%d);\n",
            gRxPacketCount, gRxTimeOutCount);

    return;
}

Application (outside of main):
// User Defined function called when a packet is recieved.
void user_CANRxCallBackFunction(VL_USB_CAN_XFER* pRxPacket, int txStatus)
{
    /* ***** Declarations. ***** */
    /* ************************* */

    /* ***** Initializations. ***** */
    /* **************************** */

    /* ***** PROCESS. ***** */
    if (gAPIDebugLevel >= VL_DEBUG_2)
    {
        printf("Entering app userDefinedRxFunction(), txStatus=%d\n", txStatus);
    }

    if (txStatus == LIBUSB_TRANSFER_COMPLETED)
    {
        if (pRxPacket->cmd == USB_CAN_CMD_RX)
        {
            gCurRxPktCount++;
            gCurTxRxPktCount++;

            (void)VSL_CANPrintPktHeader("Packet Received:", pRxPacket);
            CANPrintPacket(pRxPacket);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        gFailedPktCount++;
    }
    /* ******************** */

    if (gAPIDebugLevel >= VL_DEBUG_2)
        printf("Leaving app userDefinedRxFunction()\n");

    return;
}

How can I get Visual Studio to prioritize the application definition?

Are you programming in C or in C++? They are two very different languages, and should seldom be tagged together. Please only tag the language you're actually program in.

FYI, in C++ you don't need typedef struct.  The name of the struct can be used as a type.

In C++ you should be passing by reference.  A reference by definition exists.  A pointer can point to anywhere and there is no simple method to verify that a pointer is pointing to a valid object or location.

Windows and Linux dynamic linkers work differently, Linux dynamic linker allows function in the executable to override functions in shared objects with the same name, windows dynamic linker doesn't allow that.
The DLL needs to be modified to allow this functionality, the C way is to expose a global exported function pointer, and bind it to a default value, then override it in the main application.
// in DLL
typedef void (*func_type)(VL_USB_CAN_XFER* , int);
__declspec(dllexport) func_type user_CANRxCallBackFunction = some_inital_function;

// in executable
__declspec(dllimport) func_type user_CANRxCallBackFunction;

// somewhere in main
user_CANRxCallBackFunction = some_new_function;

C++ adds a lot to make this code more flexible, the biggest change is that you can use std::function instead to hold any callable, not just function pointers, as well as the ability to provide an OOP interface instead of using globals and function pointers.
