Linking flag exe to dll in c++ mfc
I have two C++ projects: one is an executable (EXE), and the other is a dynamic link library (DLL). In the EXE project, I am using a flag corresponding to a checkbox, and I need to access the value of this flag from within the DLL project.
To achieve this, I created a header file that utilizes __declspec(dllexport) and __declspec(dllimport) for proper symbol sharing between the EXE and DLL. Here's how I have defined it:
#pragma once

#ifdef BUILDING_DLL
    #define SHARED_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define SHARED_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// Declare the shared variable
extern "C" SHARED_API bool g_bEnableBluetoothPortChecking;

// Declare the getter and setter functions
extern "C" SHARED_API bool GetBluetoothPortCheckingState();
extern "C" SHARED_API void SetBluetoothPortCheckingState(bool state);

This header is included in both the EXE and DLL projects. However, I am encountering the following issues:

Dependency Errors: When attempting to retrieve the flag value from the EXE within the DLL, I am facing dependency-related issues.

Linking Errors: When trying to set the global variable, linking errors occur.


Could you advise on the correct approach to ensure the flag is properly shared and accessed between the EXE and DLL, avoiding these dependency and linking errors in Visual Studio 2010?

Is g_bEnableBluetoothPortChecking defined somewhere in the dll project source? The extern declaration doesn't really allocate space for it.

Possible dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78427140/user-definable-function-not-working-with-visual-studio-but-does-with-gcc/78427186#78427186

The header-file you created rather suggests that both the g_bEnableBluetoothPortChecking flag and the Get()/Set() functions are defined in the dll module, exported, and "used" (imported) by the executable, as they are all dllexport for the DLL and dllimport for the EXE. If this is not what you wanted you need to rethink or restructure it. And finally I don't understand why you want to export the flag while you also have getter/setter functions.

Just flip this and have the dll contain the flag and the associated functions.

Yes I have defined the global variable g_bEnableBluetoothPortChecking in the EXE file, where I am setting the flag. In this file, I have also implemented the GetBluetoothPortCheckingState and SetBluetoothPortCheckingState functions. Through these, I am try to get the value in my DLL file

Put them in the dll instead and import them into the executable.

Doesn't the dll export other functions too? Obviously it does, otherwise you wouldn't be able to call it, so it would meaningless. Therefore this implementation is impossible, as the EXE depends on the DLL and the DLL on the EXE, ie you won't be able to build either of the two, as you won't have the import library of the other module. If the implementation of the flag and functions must reside in the EXE, there are other solutions; but then the header file source above is wrong, as noted in my previous comment, it would be OK if the dll exported them. You need to revise the code or the design.
